# graphql_flutter - copied code from the pub.dev page - still getting error

Tags: flutter, graphql

I have copied this code from the graphql_flutter pub.dev page still getting this error
when I hover over the builder. All I did is put in my query and changed some values inside the builder that relates to my query.

`Error - The argument type 'StatelessWidget Function(QueryResult, {Future Function(FetchMoreOptions) fetchMore, void Function() refetch})' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(QueryResult, {Future Function(FetchMoreOptions)? fetchMore, Future<QueryResult?> Function()? refetch})'.`

````
  final String _query = """
    query {
      users {
          id
          name
          email
      }
  } """;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Query(
      options: QueryOptions(
        document: gql(_query), // this is the query string you just created
        pollInterval: Duration(seconds: 10),
      ),
      builder: (QueryResult result, {VoidCallback refetch, FetchMore fetchMore}) {
        if (result.hasException) {
          return Text(result.exception.toString());
        }

        if (result.isLoading) {
          return Text('Loading');
        }
        List repositories = result.data['users'];
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: repositories.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final repository = repositories[index];
              return Text(repository['name']);
            });
      },
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
builder: (QueryResult result, {
                  Future<QueryResult> Function(FetchMoreOptions)? fetchMore,
                  Future<QueryResult?> Function()? refetch,
                }) {
```

Updating the builder function syntax to match the 'parameter type' works.